# Why do I have this no default constructor error? intent service error

Tags: java, android

i am trying to get the coordinates of a location through an app,however in the the manifest file,the *GPSTracker* is underlined red,saying there no default constructor,i was wondering what is the problem,thank you.Below is the tracker file code

```
public class GPSTracker extends Service implements LocationListener {

private final Context mContext;
boolean isGPSEnabled = false; // flag for GPS status
boolean isNetworkEnabled = false; // flag for network status
boolean canGetLocation = false; // flag for GPS status


Location location; // location
double latitude; // latitude
double longitude; // longitude

private static final long MIN_DISTANCE_CHANGE_FOR_UPDATES = 10; // 10 meters

private static final long MIN_TIME_BW_UPDATES = 1000 * 60 * 1;

protected LocationManager locationManager;



public GPSTracker(Context context) {
    this.mContext = context;
    getLocation();

}


public Location getLocation() {
    try {
        locationManager = 
(LocationManager)mContext.getSystemService(LOCATION_SERVICE);

        isGPSEnabled = 
locationManager.isProviderEnabled(LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER);
        // getting network status
        isNetworkEnabled = 
locationManager.isProviderEnabled(LocationManager.NETWORK_PROVIDER);

        if (!isGPSEnabled && !isNetworkEnabled) {

        } else {
            this.canGetLocation = true;
            if (isNetworkEnabled) {
                if (ActivityCompat.checkSelfPermission(mContext, 
 Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION) != 
 PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED
                        && ActivityCompat.checkSelfPermission(mContext,
                        Manifest.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION) !=
                        PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
```

Comment: How is this question related to C++? I see no C++ code, nor the mention of JNI.

Comment: the problem is that you are missing a constructor with no arguments:
`public GPSTracker(){ }`

Comment: You should have no explicitly defined constructors in a `Service`. Remove the one that you have - `public GPSTracker(Context context) { ... }`.

Answer (score 0):

You need to add default constructor to GPSTracker.

```
public GPSTracker() {
   //implement
}
```

Comment: OP's intention is to know why the exception is raised though he defined a constructor. i.e. why is it made mandate? and why is it not made mandate when no other constructor is defined? I believe OP is expecting answers for these questions

Comment: yea,but i tried it, doesn't work,instead another error of *mcontext* variable might not have been initialized

Comment: Could you please post your mainfest

Comment: <service
            android:name=".GPSTracker"
            android:enabled="false"
            android:exported="false" />

Answer (score 0):

Service inherits the context. You do not need to add another context to the constructor but write:

```
locationManager = (LocationManager)getSystemService(LOCATION_SERVICE);
```